# Run PHP command line, needs socket_create

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that needs to run from command line. One of the function it calls is `socket_create`.

In php.ini, I have included the following in order to get that function working (see the comment on http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.installation.php):

```
extension=php_sockets.dll
```

How do I run the script from command line such that it doesn't complain that `socket_create` is an unknown function? Does PHP CLI actually respect what's in php.ini? I thought it was supposed to, but I do get errors when running it via CLI and no errors when running it via the browser.

UPDATE: by the way, I'm testing this out: https://github.com/nicokaiser/php-websocket. I assume that the server needs to be executed via command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different php.ini file may apply when running php on the CLI rather than as a web server module. You appear to be using Windows, so I'm not sure where this file may be, but it could provide a clue;  look for several php.ini files in your disk and see if one of them applies to CLI invocations.

Comment: I tried running it with the -c commandline option (to specify the php.ini explicitly) and pointed it to the one the web server is using. The command: `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\php.exe -c c:\wamp\bin\php
\php5.3.9\php.ini server.php` still gave the same error.

Comment: Turns out, I made changes to the php.ini in Apache folder, but was running CLI with the php.ini in the PHP bin folder. Oops! Problem fixed now. Thanks.